# Packet filtering with Netfilter's NFQUEUE vs. Berkeley Packet Filter (BPF)

Tags: linux, iptables, netfilter, bpf

I've just read [in these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12829150/what-is-the-analogue-of-an-ndis-filter-in-linux) about two options for developing packet filters in linux.

The first is using **iptables** and **netfilter**, probably with `NFQUEUE` and [libnetfilter_queue](http://netfilter.org/projects/libnetfilter_queue/) library.

The second is by using **[BPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Packet_Filter)** (Berkeley Packet Filter), that seems in a quick reading to have similar capabilities for filtering purposes.

So, which of these alternatives is a better way to create a packet filter? What are the differences? My software is going to run as a gateway proxy, or "man-in-the-middle" that should receive a packet from one computer (with destination address to another one, not the filter's local address), and send it out after some filtering.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I probably will go with *netfilter/iptables* since from an arquitectural point of view I think is better than B/PF. For just point out an example, I like the translations order on netfilter with the {PRE|POST}ROUTING chains since they don't clash with firewall chains/rules, au contraire of BFP, which order is strange.

Comment: Thanks. By the way, if i want to release an "out-of-the-box" software (that does not require os configuration like setting firewall rules, but only a simple kind of installation), isn't it better to use bpf? however, i need more information about the differences since it's not the main consideration

Comment: Maybe, is true that it is simpler but that isn't always good.

Comment: By the way, the development in BPF is also simple or just the architecture?

Answer (score 3):

Though my understanding is limited to the theoretical, I've done some reading while debugging the Kubernetes networking implementation and can thus take a stab at answering this.

Broadly, both `netfilter` and `eBPF` (the successor to BPF) implement a virtual machine that execute some logic while processing packets. `netfilter`'s implementation appears to strive for compatibility with `iptables` previous implementation, being essentially a more performant successor to `iptables`.

However, there are still performance problems when using `iptables` -- particularly when there are large sets of `iptables` rules. The way `eBPF` is structured can alleviate some of these performance problems; specifically:

- eBPF can be offloaded to a "smart nic"
- eBPF can be structured to lookup rules more efficiently

Though it was initially used for network processing, eBPF is also being used for kernel instrumentation (sysdig, iovisor). It has a far larger set of use cases, but because of this, is likely a much tougher learning curve.

So, in summary:

- Use what you're familiar with, unless you hit perf problems then
- Look at eBPF

Relevant:

- https://cilium.io/blog/2018/11/20/fb-bpf-firewall/
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4-pawkiazEg
- https://ferrisellis.com/posts/ebpf_past_present_future/
- https://lwn.net/Articles/747551/

Notes:

- eBPF is the successor to cBPF, and has replaced it in the kernel
- I refer to eBPF explicitly here out of habit